# apt-get dpkg update with linux-image-4.4.0-130 cannot configure: half-installed

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

Ubuntu 16.04.5 cannot update after linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic:156 fails.
I have tried:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic
```

- Log file with `apt-get upgrade`:
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sBCbwWqPBI0R_oq-dSQNmn2OWERBBQvK
- Log file with `apt-get dist-upgrade`:
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rw7Ba2FS-Qig4phnBx_t6g9q2oIdz7DK

Any help on this would be preferred.  Thanks.

Comment: Most of the apt-get upgrade text happens every time I run apt-get upgrade and continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dpkg database is highly damaged. You should reinstall all mentioned packages with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-sil-abyssinica libatk-adaptor:amd64 i915-4.6.3-4.4.0-dkms libquadmath0:amd64 libxkbfile1:amd64 linux-sound-base libnpth0:amd64 libgom-1.0-common libqt5qml5:amd64 libalien-sdl-perl vdpau-driver-all:amd64 evolution-data-server libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libhtml-tagset-perl iputils-ping libcgmanager0:amd64 libxi6:amd64 libedit2:amd64 intel-gpu-tools ogmrip-oggz libsdl-net1.2:amd64 python3-cryptography vim-tiny liblist-moreutils-perl qmlscene libncurses5:amd64 baobab libpugixml1v5:amd64 hplip libart-2.0-2:amd64 libenchant1c2a:amd64 libqt5core5a:amd64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64 libgomp1:amd64 libkpathsea6:amd64 libnet-domain-tld-perl libjs-jquery libpaper1:amd64 plainbox-provider-checkbox libqt5quick5:amd64 rhythmbox-plugins libatomic1:amd64 libxaw7:amd64 libpython3-stdlib:amd64 update-inetd libreoffice-help-en-us libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 libgloox13v5:amd64 gpsd cpp gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 libxcb-present0:amd64 qtdeclarative5-dev-tools python-pip-whl libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 gir1.2-goa-1.0:amd64 xcursor-themes gir1.2-atspi-2.0 liba11y-profile-manager-0.1-0:amd64 readline-common remmina-plugin-vnc libgnomekbd-common binfmt-support makedev gnome-settings-daemon-schemas libindicator3-7 libgsettings-qt1:amd64 debhelper gitg libsratom-0-0:amd64 0ad-data gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 fonts-tlwg-garuda libcairo2:amd64 libnss-mdns:amd64 libsbc1:amd64 libvcdinfo0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 libtinfo5:amd64 usbmuxd libnotify4:amd64 libgdbm3:amd64 libnet-libidn-perl libfontconfig1:amd64 manpages xserver-xorg-video-intel libcairomm-1.0-1v5:amd64 gconf2-common mountall strace python3-speechd libmpeg2-4:amd64 libhybris libxcb-composite0:amd64 libnettle6:amd64 libtdb1:amd64 python-setuptools libsidplay2v5 libxinerama1:amd64 libgeocode-glib0:amd64 libopencolorio1v5 aptdaemon-data unity-gtk-module-common ufw libxcb-dri2-0:amd64 libsm6:amd64 deja-dup libmms0:amd64 cpio libdee-1.0-4:amd64 wbritish libappstream-glib8:amd64 libpopt0:amd64 libsecret-common libflac++6v5:amd64 qml-module-qtquick2:amd64 powermgmt-base libxcb-dri3-0:amd64 libatasmart4:amd64 kmod libattr1:amd64 libdaemon0:amd64 libxcb-render-util0:amd64 libk5crypto3:amd64 fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf libss2:amd64 gir1.2-notify-0.7 libxcb-glx0:amd64 rtmpdump libgnome2-common libxcb-randr0:amd64 openoffice.org-hyphenation libraptor2-0:amd64 libcommons-io-java libwebpmux1:amd64 libqt4-declarative:amd64 fonts-tlwg-typist dvd+rw-tools python3-xlsxwriter libunity-gtk3-parser0:amd64 xserver-xorg-input-all libestr0 libexpat1:amd64 libpaper-utils speech-dispatcher libical1a:amd64 secureboot-db libqt5dbus5:amd64 libcc1-0:amd64 libgphoto2-port12:amd64 libmailtools-perl libcheese8:amd64 gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 less libmwaw-0.3-3:amd64 python3-pycurl libaccounts-qt5-1:amd64 libid3tag0 libfont-afm-perl gtk2-engines-murrine:amd64 libwnck-3-common libtwolame0:amd64 language-pack-en-base gir1.2-atk-1.0 lp-solve libqtgui4:amd64 libraw1394-11:amd64 fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf libjaxp1.3-java make liblzma5:amd64 libjson-glib-1.0-common fontconfig-config filezilla libsidplay1v5 geany libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libxcb-xfixes0:amd64 zenity libusageenvironment3:amd64 libqqwing2v5:amd64 python3-pil:amd64 libxcb-icccm4:amd64 libqt5feedback5:amd64 libhttp-date-perl tk8.6 libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64 python3-cups libgtksourceview-3.0-1:amd64 libsdl-gfx1.2-5:amd64 libzmq5:amd64 libdouble-conversion1v5:amd64 libxcb-render0:amd64 libnet-smtp-ssl-perl mencoder libmatroska6v5:amd64 libopenjp2-7:amd64 libsignon-qt5-1:amd64 libnetfilter-conntrack3:amd64 libgnome-keyring-common gnome-calendar printer-driver-hpcups libtag1v5:amd64 libopencv-ml2.4v5:amd64 libasyncns0:amd64 libhtml-format-perl liblangtag1:amd64 gconf2 libqt5x11extras5:amd64 aisleriot libemail-valid-perl libpango1.0-0:amd64 libxml-twig-perl xbrlapi libqt5widgets5:amd64 libcogl-path20:amd64 libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64 python3-dbus libcdio13:amd64 grep qt-at-spi:amd64 libbrasero-media3-1:amd64 libecal-1.2-19:amd64 libx264-148:amd64 glib-networking-common ecryptfs-utils info signond im-config libapt-pkg-perl libportaudio2:amd64 libspnav0 libtinyxml2.6.2v5:amd64 libcmis-0.5-5v5:amd64 libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 libqt5network5:amd64 libglewmx1.13:amd64 xserver-xorg-video-qxl libharfbuzz-icu0:amd64 ibus-table libmimic0:amd64 wireless-tools librhythmbox-core9:amd64 tex-common libwnck-3-0:amd64 x11-session-utils libgjs0e inputattach nautilus-data libmodplug1:amd64 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwacom-common libwacom2:amd64 fs-uae-launcher libxdamage1:amd64 ppp fonts-stix gsettings-ubuntu-schemas dosfstools libzeitgeist-2.0-0:amd64 psmisc ogmrip-video-copy libgeoclue0:amd64 gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 base-passwd libva-glx1:amd64 libopencv-calib3d2.4v5:amd64 unity-scope-texdoc librsvg2-2:amd64 mkvtoolnix libxcb-image0:amd64 unity-settings-daemon libde265-0:amd64 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common usb-creator-common toshset python3-pyatspi libgcr-base-3-1:amd64 indicator-printers iio-sensor-proxy e2fslibs:amd64 liblz4-1:amd64 libgpod4:amd64 telepathy-idle sound-theme-freedesktop signon-keyring-extension qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin:amd64 python3-plainbox indicator-datetime time libxext6:amd64 libmpx0:amd64 libcogl-common liboxideqtcore0:amd64 debianutils liblilv-0-0 libxfixes3:amd64 po-debconf mime-support fonts-tlwg-sawasdee gsettings-desktop-schemas fonts-tlwg-typewriter libio-socket-inet6-perl libsvm3-java cheese-common example-content ureadahead libaudiofile1:amd64 session-shortcuts python3 geoclue libio-pty-perl x11-xkb-utils python3-selinux libwind0-heimdal:amd64 gsfonts libevdev2:amd64 audacity ttf-dejavu-core libhttp-cookies-perl python3-cffi-backend gir1.2-rb-3.0:amd64 libfile-which-perl libqt5organizer5:amd64 fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf gnome-calculator libencode-locale-perl python3-lxml libperlio-gzip-perl libwebrtc-audio-processing-0:amd64 libboost-date-time1.58.0:amd64 libtext-levenshtein-perl vino app-install-data usb-creator-gtk libtrove3-java gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0:amd64 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 hwdata geoip-database ruby-test-unit libgeoclue-2-0:amd64 pcmciautils libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:amd64 xinit libjemalloc1 sudo language-pack-gnome-en iso-codes libcanberra0:amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic notify-osd rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist libncursesw5:amd64 fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf python3-brlapi libzbar0:amd64 liberror-perl libdjvulibre21:amd64 dconf-service gettext gir1.2-wnck-3.0:amd64 libv4l-0:amd64 ltrace python-notify bash libdvbpsi10:amd64 xserver-xorg-input-evdev libqt4-script:amd64 libedataserverui-1.2-1:amd64 activity-log-manager libopenjpeg5:amd64 libodfgen-0.1-1 libaccounts-glib0:amd64 remmina-common libtimedate-perl dictionaries-common libmpcdec6:amd64 qml-module-qttest:amd64 webapp-container liblcms2-2:amd64 libnet-ip-perl dmidecode libjbig0:amd64 libvisio-0.1-1:amd64 libpcsclite1:amd64 fonts-lklug-sinhala libgrits5 libgpm2:amd64 libgtk-3-common rename thermald libgps22:amd64 midori libnet-ssleay-perl build-essential libcompress-bzip2-perl zeitgeist-datahub python3-mako libaspell15:amd64 gir1.2-signon-1.0 libva-wayland1:amd64 libcogl20:amd64 fonts-dejavu-core libarchive13:amd64 fonts-lohit-guru xbitmaps poppler-data liba11y-profile-manager-data xserver-xorg-video-nouveau libgee-0.8-2:amd64 gir1.2-vte-2.91:amd64 libxres1:amd64 libqt5webkit5:amd64 libdvdnav4:amd64 python3-commandnotfound libcilkrts5:amd64 network-manager-pptp libdjvulibre-text libbonobo2-common liborcus-0.10-0v5:amd64 hardening-includes install-info libmspub-0.1-1:amd64 efibootmgr libcap2-bin libx86-1:amd64 libdbus-glib-1-2:amd64 libwhoopsie-preferences0 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic debconf debconf-i18n zlib1g:amd64 qml-module-qtquick-layouts:amd64 libexttextcat-2.0-0:amd64 unity-scope-zotero libopencv-legacy2.4v5:amd64 printer-driver-postscript-hp libvte-2.91-0:amd64 fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf libsane:amd64 alsa-base libcanberra-gtk3-module:amd64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad:amd64 librsl1 gir1.2-freedesktop:amd64 espeak-data:amd64 libtotem0:amd64 gnome-screensaver libblas-common libgtop2-common libbasicusageenvironment1:amd64 lsof gnome-system-log libaacs0:amd64 libsignon-glib1:amd64 system-config-printer-common default-jre hostname system-config-printer-udev libproxy-tools libgtkmm-3.0-1v5:amd64 gir1.2-peas-1.0:amd64 libboost-system1.58.0:amd64 bash-completion gir1.2-accounts-1.0:amd64 init libgom-1.0-0:amd64 libgtkglext1:amd64 libwpd-0.10-10:amd64 qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin:amd64 libiso9660-8:amd64 libtbb2:amd64 gpac-modules-base:amd64 crda python3-pyqt5 libipc-system-simple-perl libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 mawk libxml-commons-external-java printer-driver-sag-gdi liblouisutdml-data libv4lconvert0:amd64 libfile-basedir-perl gzip libubsan0:amd64 rake deja-dup-backend-gvfs libatspi2.0-0:amd64 libdbusmenu-qt5:amd64 libcheese-gtk25:amd64 p11-kit libtsan0:amd64 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64 libyaml-cpp0.3v5:amd64 gnome-user-guide libflite1:amd64 ubuntu-settings qtcore4-l10n libgfortran3:amd64 lightyears mscompress groff-base libcdio-cdda1:amd64 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic liblapack3 python3-padme libldb1:amd64 libsoxr0:amd64 libtk8.6:amd64 at-spi2-core java-wrappers language-selector-common libabw-0.1-1v5:amd64 evolution-data-server-common libcanberra-pulse:amd64 printer-driver-foo2zjs-common libglib2.0-0:amd64 libssh-gcrypt-4:amd64 unity-lens-files libxss1:amd64 libcolamd2.9.1:amd64 libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64 libasound2-data libnetpbm10 libxshmfence1:amd64 ubuntu-wallpapers gir1.2-udisks-2.0:amd64 fonts-tlwg-purisa libebml4v5:amd64 libcapture-tiny-perl dosbox emacsen-common indicator-application account-plugin-google libao4:amd64 ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme gnome-video-effects libcap2:amd64 syslinux-legacy libdata-alias-perl libclutter-1.0-common acpi-support fonts-guru-extra libio-html-perl python3-idna libexporter-tiny-perl libgconf-2-4:amd64 libhud2:amd64 whiptail qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin dash libfuse2:amd64 python3-xdg libunity-action-qt1:amd64 totem-common libcairo-gobject2:amd64 xkb-data qtchooser libe-book-0.1-1:amd64 gcc-6-base:amd64 gcc-6-base:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 system-config-printer-gnome python-wheel python-gtk2 qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts:amd64 libenet7:amd64 libfcitx-utils0:amd64 ogmrip-dirac libva-tpi1:amd64 liblwp-protocol-https-perl unity-scopes-master-default python3-six libxtables11:amd64 libunity-misc4 libpangoxft-1.0-0:amd64 libopencv-contrib2.4v5:amd64 libproxy1v5:amd64 unzip libudisks2-0:amd64 libgexiv2-2:amd64 libtie-ixhash-perl libgtop-2.0-10:amd64 libgnomevfs2-common libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 fonts-tlwg-umpush java-common qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:amd64 libfaad2:amd64 libkate1:amd64 0ad-data-common fonts-wqy-microhei vainfo libx11-6:amd64 hoichess libqt5test5:amd64 libsasl2-2:amd64 libflac8:amd64 gnome-terminal-data libnatpmp1:amd64 pptp-linux libmusicbrainz5-2:amd64 genisoimage dbus-x11 oxideqt-codecs:amd64 libtelepathy-logger3:amd64 ogmrip-ac3 adium-theme-ubuntu python3-pyparsing keyutils tcl libasound2-plugins:amd64 libgphoto2-6:amd64 libao-common telepathy-mission-control-5 libcommons-logging-java mlocate libdirectfb-1.2-9:amd64 libgc1c2:amd64 libsuil-0-0:amd64 libunity-settings-daemon1:amd64 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 libspandsp2:amd64 libsdl-mixer1.2:amd64 openprinting-ppds geany-common libvdpau1:amd64 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic libbatik-java libvpx3:amd64 libsdl-perl x11-utils fonts-guru python3-dev libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 whoopsie-preferences xboard libchromaprint0:amd64 xserver-xorg-video-all libsdl1.2debian:amd64 libasan2:amd64 libprotobuf9v5:amd64 libharfbuzz0b:amd64 python3-guacamole libsord-0-0:amd64 glib-networking-services session-migration libmedia1 libdc1394-22:amd64 libdatrie1:amd64 libwxgtk3.0-0v5:amd64 gettext-base libshine3:amd64 gnome-session-canberra ssl-cert libgrail6 xfonts-utils libgutenprint2 libgif7:amd64 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:amd64 libhttp-daemon-perl telepathy-logger dconf-cli ogmrip-doc python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets libpipeline1:amd64 libebook-1.2-16:amd64 libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 libopencv-core2.4v5:amd64 libnet-dbus-perl libroken18-heimdal:amd64 libpagemaker-0.0-0:amd64 libfcitx-gclient0:amd64 appstream pm-utils libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64 udisks2 xserver-xorg-video-vmware syslinux libiec61883-0:amd64 libpcre3:amd64 youtube-dl apturl libksba8:amd64 fonts-ancient-scripts libthai0:amd64 libqt4-sql-sqlite:amd64 librtmp1:amd64 gir1.2-dee-1.0 fonts-texgyre libgdata22:amd64 humanity-icon-theme plainbox-provider-resource-generic unity-scope-manpages libxcb-util1:amd64 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 libqt4-sql:amd64 python3-wheel libopencv-features2d2.4v5:amd64 python3-gi-cairo libspeex1:amd64 pppconfig apg notify-osd-icons upower gcc unity-webapps-common command-not-found libfreenect0.5:amd64 qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64 sgml-base hplip-data python3-pkg-resources gnome-icon-theme xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse libgeoip1:amd64 libxvmc1:amd64 libcolorhug2:amd64 python-pkg-resources appmenu-qt5 python3-gi qml-module-qt-labs-settings:amd64 libnet-dns-perl python3-bs4 libyelp0:amd64 dmz-cursor-theme libclucene-core1v5:amd64 fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf lsb-release coreutils syslinux-common ed libopenexr22:amd64 libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64 librevenge-0.0-0:amd64 signon-plugin-oauth2 xterm libfftw3-double3:amd64 libcdparanoia0:amd64 libmng2:amd64 libxvidcore4:amd64 fonts-noto-cjk libcolumbus1-common fakeroot usbutils libandroid-properties1 tcpd libipset3:amd64 printer-driver-splix liblircclient0:amd64 libappstream3:amd64 libgtk-3-0:amd64 libmtp-runtime libbsd0:amd64 qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics:amd64 remmina qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside:amd64 indicator-session fairymax libsrtp0 libqt5printsupport5:amd64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers:amd64 simple-scan qml-module-ubuntu-web:amd64 fonts-liberation signon-ui libyaml-tiny-perl libgnome-2-0:amd64 libpangomm-1.4-1v5:amd64 e2fsprogs fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf libaccount-plugin-1.0-0:amd64 tar libkrb5support0:amd64 unity-lens-photos xdg-user-dirs-gtk libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 laptop-detect libbz2-1.0:amd64 libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64 python3-slip fonts-tlwg-laksaman gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 libnspr4:amd64 libunity-webapps0:amd64 ucf whoopsie xfonts-encodings libgphoto2-l10n fonts-symbola libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 libsuitesparseconfig4.4.6:amd64 unity-scope-gdrive librsvg2-common:amd64 libkmod2:amd64 libio-socket-ssl-perl libebook-contacts-1.2-2:amd64 unity-webapps-qml libxmuu1:amd64 python-numpy libecryptfs1 media-player-info libutempter0:amd64 zip libguess1:amd64 libqt5opengl5:amd64 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 libmtp-common libboost-locale1.58.0:amd64 gnome-mines indicator-keyboard libqt5multimedia5:amd64 python3-markupsafe gnome-terminal librsync1:amd64 mousetweaks libgnome-keyring0:amd64 libsonic0:amd64 libcgi-fast-perl libhtml-tree-perl libtie-simple-perl ubuntu-session gstreamer1.0-tools vdpau-va-driver:amd64 xserver-xorg-video-radeon libgck-1-0:amd64 fonts-tlwg-waree linux-headers-4.4.0-71 indicator-messages libspeechd2:amd64 liblouisutdml-bin libstartup-notification0:amd64 a11y-profile-manager-indicator gucharmap libmhash2:amd64 libopus0:amd64 libxtst6:amd64 libfreetype6:amd64 libxmu6:amd64 duplicity libva1:amd64 ceferino qdbus unity-gtk3-module:amd64 libwxbase3.0-0v5:amd64 libasound2:amd64 ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial gir1.2-pango-1.0:amd64 libneon27-gnutls:amd64 gnome-chess bzip2 blender-data libopenal-data libx265-79:amd64 libgpod-common libjson-glib-1.0-0:amd64 libgcr-3-common lsb-base libhogweed4:amd64 netcat-openbsd libsane-common app-install-data-partner unity-scope-calculator libgeonames0:amd64 liblsan0:amd64 gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0:amd64 libboost-regex1.58.0:amd64 libbs2b0:amd64 usb-modeswitch-data libcroco3:amd64 libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64 blender libgpgme11:amd64 libxcb-sync1:amd64 fonts-lato libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 liblept5 bleachbit libbonobo2-0:amd64 libxslt1.1:amd64 xauth libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 python3-defer libnotify-bin libcommons-parent-java p7zip-full pppoeconf libaccountsservice0:amd64 libass5:amd64 libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 unity-control-center-signon libgpg-error0:amd64 appmenu-qt:amd64 gconf-service libvo-aacenc0:amd64 mobile-broadband-provider-info libcolumbus1v5:amd64 eog xserver-xorg fonts-kacst-one libogg0:amd64 libwildmidi1:amd64 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 python3-blinker libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 libsys-hostname-long-perl unity-scope-openclipart libmikmod3:amd64 libxerces2-java unity-scope-home python3-reportlab esound-common file-roller libmediaart-2.0-0:amd64 libwildmidi-config liboauth0:amd64 indicator-power libjline-java libhardware2 libtevent0:amd64 libburn4:amd64 python-gobject-2 busybox-initramfs libfile-fcntllock-perl python3-feedparser libsndfile1:amd64 gnome-screenshot libgsoap8:amd64 libubuntutoolkit5:amd64 libilmbase12:amd64 fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf libalgorithm-merge-perl libatk1.0-data gnome-system-monitor nano i965-va-driver:amd64 lame libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0:amd64 pithos libglade2-0:amd64 libsgutils2-2 intltool-debian libclucene-contribs1v5:amd64 libhybris-common1 liba52-0.7.4:amd64 printer-driver-min12xxw tesseract-ocr-osd libfcitx-config4:amd64 polari libpwquality1:amd64 libgettextpo0:amd64 pkg-config libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java liblqr-1-0:amd64 libyajl2:amd64 gnome-sudoku libjbig2dec0 ruby-did-you-mean libhyphen0:amd64 python3-pyqt5.qtopengl libisl15:amd64 libyaml-0-2:amd64 libx11-xcb1:amd64 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libgmp10:amd64 libgtk-3-bin libwacom-bin gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks cabextract libpixman-1-0:amd64 python-gi gnome-weather python3-pyasn1 aften gnome-mahjongg tesseract-ocr-eng dh-strip-nondeterminism acpid gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4:amd64 libmp3lame0:amd64 geoclue-ubuntu-geoip libedataserver-1.2-21:amd64 geoclue-2.0 unity-webapps-service libblas3 fonts-sil-padauk language-pack-en gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64 libdbusmenu-gtk4:amd64 grilo-plugins-0.2-base:amd64 libvte-2.91-common libssh2-1:amd64 ubuntu-touch-sounds printer-driver-pxljr libcanberra-gtk-module:amd64 libglib2.0-data usb-modeswitch libxalan2-java p11-kit-modules:amd64 libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64 passwd cups-pk-helper init-system-helpers fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf fonts-nanum libusb-1.0-0:amd64 liblwp-mediatypes-perl libqt5quicktest5:amd64 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl hyphen-en-us libaccount-plugin-google colord-data xserver-xorg-video-vesa libtracker-sparql-1.0-0:amd64 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:amd64 libunwind8 checkbox-converged libmail-sendmail-perl libvo-amrwbenc0:amd64 libaa1:amd64 gnome-user-share ncurses-base liboxideqtquick0:amd64 libcrystalhd3:amd64 tk krb5-locales libxxf86dga1:amd64 libframe6:amd64 colord fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf pyotherside libsemanage1:amd64 ceferino-data libqtcore4:amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 remmina-plugin-rdp libfile-desktopentry-perl libupnp6 libedata-cal-1.2-28:amd64 libqt5xml5:amd64 libmessaging-menu0:amd64 libsocket6-perl pinentry-gnome3 apturl-common libgcr-ui-3-1:amd64 alsa-utils libatm1:amd64 elki patchutils gir1.2-secret-1:amd64 python3-oauthlib libqt5positioning5:amd64 libepoxy0:amd64 autotools-dev librasqal3:amd64 metacity-common ubuntu-system-service libunistring0:amd64 libgrilo-0.2-1:amd64 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu liborbit-2-0:amd64 fonts-tlwg-mono iptables indicator-sound iputils-tracepath python3-pexpect gir1.2-json-1.0:amd64 libbsf-java python3-chardet libdotconf0:amd64 webbrowser-app python3-slip-dbus iucode-tool libxapian22v5:amd64 libasprintf0v5:amd64 libefivar0:amd64 libqt5gui5:amd64 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:amd64 liburi-perl libgnome-menu-3-0:amd64 kbd python3-aptdaemon overlay-scrollbar python3-systemd t1utils libeot0:amd64 libuuid-perl policykit-1-gnome libdiscid0:amd64 xdiagnose libexttextcat-data libatk1.0-0:amd64 sysvinit-utils xz-utils unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks bsdgames fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf doc-base libportmidi0 libtext-iconv-perl ogmrip-plugins:amd64 telnet libxcb-xv0:amd64 libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 fonts-takao-pgothic libqt5svg5:amd64 ipset libsnappy1v5:amd64 language-pack-gnome-en-base libmusicbrainz5cc2v5:amd64 libhttp-parser2.1:amd64 mtools gnome-bluetooth va-driver-all:amd64 libgmime-2.6-0:amd64 qml-module-qtquick-window2:amd64 libbluray1:amd64 unity-lens-video fonts-tlwg-kinnari ippusbxd gpac seahorse account-plugin-flickr qttranslations5-l10n sessioninstaller unity-scope-video-remote dc python3-jinja2 cheese python3-html5lib glib-networking:amd64 libtext-wrapi18n-perl aptdaemon rhythmbox zeitgeist-core libsemanage-common libmythes-1.2-0:amd64 libgxps2:amd64 libfakeroot:amd64 hud rtkit libgucharmap-2-90-7:amd64 guile-2.0-libs:amd64 libp11-kit0:amd64 libpango-1.0-0:amd64 libssh-4:amd64 libgit2-24:amd64 libcddb2 python3-minimal libgcc-5-dev:amd64 libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager:amd64 libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 gdisk ntfs-3g libdebconfclient0:amd64 libselinux1:amd64 gnome-keyring tcl8.6 mtr-tiny libltdl7:amd64 libpwquality-common libhtml-parser-perl libxml-parser-perl unity-scope-tomboy libgusb2:amd64 aspell-en libmtp9:amd64 libmtdev1:amd64 libqt5sql5:amd64 libipc-run-perl libapache-pom-java fonts-tlwg-loma-ttf lightdm libcdr-0.1-1:amd64 gedit-common python3-httplib2 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:amd64 libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 signon-plugin-password ftp sbsigntool libupower-glib3:amd64 python3-pip ruby-net-telnet libtimezonemap1:amd64 ubuntu-sounds libavc1394-0:amd64 libboost-iostreams1.58.0:amd64 unity-scope-devhelp libcogl-pango20:amd64 libsignon-plugins-common1:amd64 vim-common fonts-tlwg-norasi libcgi-pm-perl libijs-0.35:amd64 apport-symptoms libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 xfonts-100dpi liboggz2 libsqlite3-0:amd64 libjack-jackd2-0:amd64 libofa0:amd64 libetonyek-0.1-1:amd64 lintian libhtml-form-perl gedit jayatana libva-egl1:amd64 netpbm libboost-thread1.58.0:amd64 zenity-common python3-sip libvisual-0.4-0:amd64 libice6:amd64 libogmrip1:amd64 libfontenc1:amd64 libdigest-hmac-perl python3-requests python-cairo libdconf1:amd64 libfile-listing-perl libclutter-gst-3.0-0:amd64 vorbis-tools libxcomposite1:amd64 libio-string-perl sysv-rc libgroupsock8:amd64 fonts-lao libglew1.13:amd64 libalgorithm-diff-perl printer-driver-foo2zjs libiw30:amd64 libzvbi-common libfribidi0:amd64 libxcb-shm0:amd64 sound-juicer liblocale-gettext-perl qml-module-ubuntu-test:amd64 libmpfr4:amd64 libgtkspell3-3-0:amd64 libgettextpo-dev:amd64 libgail-3-0:amd64 libpangox-1.0-0:amd64 dmsetup libxpm4:amd64 python3-cupshelpers libclone-perl libcanberra-gtk3-0:amd64 rubygems-integration libasprintf-dev:amd64 libesd0:amd64 x11-xserver-utils evolution-data-server-online-accounts libxt6:amd64 gjs enchant libexpat1-dev:amd64 libpciaccess0:amd64 libxcb-shape0:amd64 libxrender1:amd64 gkbd-capplet liblangtag-common libfftw3-single3:amd64 python3-gdbm:amd64 diffutils speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:amd64 libopencore-amrnb0:amd64 liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 libparse-debianchangelog-perl libxv1:amd64 libido3-0.1-0:amd64 libx11-protocol-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl ttf-ubuntu-font-family filezilla-common libsensors4:amd64 man-db shared-mime-info libxkbcommon0:amd64 libhttp-message-perl indicator-appmenu g++ libglu1-mesa:amd64 libgoa-1.0-common libnet-http-perl libnfnetlink0:amd64 libgudev-1.0-0:amd64 libopenal1:amd64 librest-0.7-0:amd64 python-pygame gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 gnome-session-bin libsmpeg0:amd64 librhino-java libisofs6:amd64 gir1.2-gudev-1.0:amd64 python3-urllib3 printer-driver-pnm2ppa libxcb-keysyms1:amd64 gdbserver libxmlgraphics-commons-java libmpc3:amd64 insserv libjte1:amd64 libstdc++6:amd64 libtalloc2:amd64 libkrb5-3:amd64 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 libwps-0.4-4:amd64 libquvi7:amd64 libtotem-plparser-common libcamel-1.2-54:amd64 yelp-xsl python3-cairo gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 libffi6:amd64 unity-scope-virtualbox ubuntu-docs libcdio-paranoia1:amd64 libva-drm1:amd64 libtext-charwidth-perl qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin:amd64 tesseract-ocr gcc-5 printer-driver-c2esp aweather liblua5.2-0:amd64 busybox-static x11-apps libhunspell-1.3-0:amd64 libopenimageio1.6 liborc-0.4-0:amd64 gnome-menus libpcre16-3:amd64 libglibmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 liblivemedia50:amd64 xfonts-scalable unity-gtk2-module:amd64 libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 libgme0:amd64 libcomerr2:amd64 libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 libtcl8.6:amd64 libnvtt2:amd64 libwpg-0.3-3:amd64 iw libquvi-scripts libcolord2:amd64 libthai-data findutils brltty accountsservice intel-graphics-update-tool libportsmf0v5:amd64 fonts-khmeros-core librubberband2v5:amd64 libsodium18:amd64 libxdmcp6:amd64 python-lockfile xml-core javascript-common libcap-ng0:amd64 libbdplus0:amd64 ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 signon-ui-service libmad0:amd64 dbus gparted ethtool libxxf86vm1:amd64 libresid-builder0c2a libndp0:amd64 libzvbi0:amd64 g++-5 libcanberra-gtk0:amd64 wamerican unity-lens-music liburl-dispatcher1:amd64 xserver-xorg-input-wacom unity-accessibility-profiles librdf0:amd64 libkeyutils1:amd64 sni-qt:amd64 libsoundtouch1:amd64 libnewt0.52:amd64 htop bsdmainutils libopencv-objdetect2.4v5:amd64 anacron python3-setuptools libsbsms10:amd64 libxft2:amd64 unity-asset-pool overlay-scrollbar-gtk2:amd64 libopencv-flann2.4v5:amd64 ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola libsasl2-modules:amd64 libgeis1:amd64 libcaca0:amd64 login bc libmetacity-private3a:amd64 libdca0:amd64 aspell python3-pylast gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 ogmrip libappindicator3-1 libevent-2.0-5:amd64 libserd-0-0:amd64 libsamplerate0:amd64 libsndio6.1:amd64 freepats libopencv-video2.4v5:amd64 fonts-tlwg-typo libnl-3-200:amd64 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat libmission-control-plugins0:amd64 libqt4-dbus:amd64 libfile-sharedir-perl xserver-xorg-input-synaptics libtelepathy-glib0:amd64 ttf-mscorefonts-installer fonts-dejavu-extra account-plugin-facebook fonts-freefont-ttf net-tools gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 libgdata-common adduser ruby-minitest initscripts kerneloops-daemon libgpac4:amd64 libusbmuxd4:amd64 x11-common brasero-common libhpmud0:amd64 gnome-font-viewer fonts-sil-gentium unity-lens-applications libunity-gtk2-parser0:amd64 ruby libtesseract3 libsub-name-perl libieee1284-3:amd64 yelp iputils-arping libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tibetan-machine libacl1:amd64 libschroedinger-1.0-0:amd64 manpages-dev libtheora0:amd64 unity-greeter language-selector-gnome ncurses-bin libyaml-libyaml-perl libwebp5:amd64 libmpg123-0:amd64 libfile-mimeinfo-perl python-pip gir1.2-totem-1.0:amd64 libopencore-amrwb0:amd64 hicolor-icon-theme acl libshout3:amd64 fonts-kacst irqbalance rhythmbox-data qml-module-qtfeedback:amd64 libsecret-1-0:amd64 dh-python libglib2.0-bin dconf-gsettings-backend:amd64 frozen-bubble-data libslang2:amd64 python3-decorator rhino policykit-desktop-privileges libsdl-sound1.2:amd64 cron libmnl0:amd64 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 command-not-found-data gnome-desktop3-data fonts-thai-tlwg libexif12:amd64 fonts-sil-gentium-basic gir1.2-gdata-0.0:amd64 python3-ptyprocess oggz-tools sane-utils libsdl-pango1:amd64 libwmf0.2-7:amd64 libassuan0:amd64 gdb indicator-bluetooth libbabeltrace-ctf1:amd64 libfcgi-perl unity-scope-colourlovers vbetool python3-checkbox-support libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64 libqt4-network:amd64 libenca0:amd64 libboost-filesystem1.58.0:amd64 libqtdbus4:amd64 cpp-5 libfluidsynth1:amd64 onboard-data libprotobuf-lite9v5:amd64 printer-driver-ptouch libwww-robotrules-perl libxcb1:amd64 libimobiledevice6:amd64 libusb-0.1-4:amd64 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5:amd64 qml-module-ubuntu-layouts:amd64 gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64 liblouisutdml6:amd64 libgsm1:amd64 python3-debian libwhoopsie0:amd64 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 libnih1:amd64 printer-driver-gutenprint totem libpeas-common gir1.2-gtksource-3.0:amd64 libzeitgeist-1.0-1:amd64 mpv libtimezonemap-data libauthen-sasl-perl libfilezilla0 unity-scope-yelp libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 hunspell-en-us libsepol1:amd64 checkbox-gui libitm1:amd64 gnome-power-manager libx11-data qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel:amd64 diffstat libmplex2-2.1-0 libgit2-glib-1.0-0:amd64 libspeexdsp1:amd64 libqt4-xml:amd64 libxau6:amd64 branding-ubuntu memtest86+ libbabeltrace1:amd64 libmpdec2:amd64 signon-ui-x11 fuse rsyslog libclass-accessor-perl libxrandr2:amd64 ubuntu-keyring fs-uae libdbus-1-3:amd64 xorg-docs-core mplayer libva-x11-1:amd64 fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf pterm libgcc1:amd64 gconf-service-backend plainbox-secure-policy gnome-orca libreadline6:amd64 xfonts-base onboard 0ad gcr libdv4:amd64 libgnome-desktop-3-12:amd64 libaudio2:amd64 libtag1v5-vanilla:amd64 gcc-5-base:amd64 gcc-5-base:i386 libustr-1.0-1:amd64 fontconfig libbrlapi0.6:amd64 libubuntugestures5:amd64 libfreehand-0.1-1:amd64 libspectre1:amd64 libclass-inspector-perl liblzo2-2:amd64 libnih-dbus1:amd64 libsane-hpaio:amd64 libespeak1:amd64 xorg audacity-data libjson-c2:amd64 libwrap0:amd64 libfile-copy-recursive-perl libatkmm-1.6-1v5:amd64 ruby-power-assert libgnomekbd8:amd64 python3-renderpm:amd64 eject ttf-ancient-fonts mythes-en-us gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3:amd64 xinput default-jre-headless libhttp-negotiate-perl libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 libdvdread4:amd64 sed totem-plugins libdmapsharing-3.0-2:amd64 libsignon-extension1:amd64 libstdc++-5-dev:amd64 printer-driver-brlaser liblcms2-utils python3-xkit popularity-contest libwww-perl foomatic-db-compressed-ppds frozen-bubble libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64 tesseract-ocr-equ xserver-xorg-video-ati libtotem-plparser18:amd64 ogmtools network-manager-pptp-gnome libpcap0.8:amd64 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0:amd64 netbase fonts-dejavu libxklavier16:amd64 libvamp-hostsdk3v5:amd64 growisofs gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 qtdeclarative5-test-plugin:amd64 liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl libpython3-dev:amd64 mesa-utils libjpeg8:amd64 python-talloc gnome-session-common adwaita-icon-theme libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64 libkeybinder-3.0-0:amd64 libxcb-xkb1:amd64
```

If you get something like

```
E: Unable to locate package i915-4.6.3-4.4.0-dkms
```

you should remove this package from `apt-get` command and retry.

`System.map` error is fixable by `sudo touch /boot/System.map-4.4.0-130-generic`.

Then continue with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  I remember that a few months ago that I was updating it and it said that some of the files were locked, so I deleted some files that I shouldn't have done.  I finally got internet access on it, and those errors popped up.